# Temporarily disable CSS transition on window resize?

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions, window-resize

I am building a template where there are large navigation buttons at the very top that, when clicked, make a corresponding page (an absolutely positioned DIV) slide out from underneath the button and fill the whole page via CSS transitions.

I have a series of commands in a window resize function that keep everything in place/the right size if the window changes size.  It is all working fine, except for a small issue where when the page is "out", if the browser window gets resized vertically, the CSS height transition triggers as opposed to the DIV snapping to the new height instantly (the DIV is 100% width and a dynamically calculated height the makes it fill the screen below the navigation buttons exactly).  My solution to that was to add a line of code that would change the transition property to not include height BEFORE updating the height, then change it back immediately after.  It seems to do nothing at all though.  My code:

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function(event){
    bottomLoc = findBottom.getBoundingClientRect();

    if (pageOut1 == false) {
        pageLoc1 = pageButton1.getBoundingClientRect(); //redefine location variable
        document.getElementById("page1").style.top = pageLoc1.top + 70 + "px"; //update closed page position
        document.getElementById("page1").style.left = pageLoc1.left + "px"; //update closed page position
    } else if (pageOut1 == true) {
        document.getElementById("page1").style.transition = "width 0.5s, left 0.5s"; //turn off height transition
        document.getElementById("page1").style.height = bottomLoc.bottom  - 70 + "px"; //update height
        document.getElementById("page1").style.transition = "height 0.5s, width 0.5s, left 0.5s"; //turn height transition back on
    }
});
```

The part that doesn't seem to be working is in the "else if" statement.  Even though I take out the "height 0.5s" before the height update happens, it still does the transition.  This is not exactly a huge, website breaking problem, but it does cause a scroll bar to randomly appear and disappear when resized smaller, which looks bad.

Hopefully someone can help me understand why this is not working, as this would help with a lot of other templates I have that require dynamic repositioning of absolutely positioned elements.  Thanks!

Comment: Add code snippet on http://jsfiddle.net please.